# drag and drop HTML between Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge

I'm writing a small UI component that displays web links. Idea is to drag and drop link on this component, it gets url, page title and adds to the list. The source could be browser address bar, bookmark or simple link embedded in HTML page.
In order to see what data I'm receiving I've written a couple of methods:

```
dropHandler(event){
  this.traceDataTransfer(event.dataTransfer);
  event.preventDefault();
}
traceDataTransfer(data) {
  console.log(data.types);
  data.types.forEach((t) => {
    const value = data.getData(t);
    console.log(t, value.length, value);
  });
}
```

`dropHandler` is hooked on `ondrop` event.

While working with only Chrome and Firefox all is working fine. Each produces/receives slightly different data, but in general I receive the data I need. Now I add Edge browser to the mix and the encoding of text/html data from Chrome breaks down.

I drag and drop a link from html page (any source page) between Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Each browser seems to process clipboard differently, so I get different data sets between different pairs. One item that is always present and the same is the url:

```
text/uri-list 61 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer
```

`text/html` MIME type is also always present, is slightly different depending on browser combination, but in all cases contains `<a href=... >Link title</a>`. In all cases except from Chrome to Edge.

Chrome to Chrome and Firefox to Edge:

```
 text/html 101 <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer"><code>DataTransfer</code></a>
```

Chrome to Firefox:

```
 text/html 169 <html>
      <body>
      <!--StartFragment--><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer"><code>DataTransfer</code></a><!--EndFragment-->
      </body>
 </html>
```

Chrome to Edge:

```
 text/html 56 愼栠敲㵦栢瑴獰⼺搯癥汥...
```

Edge to Chrome is ok as well, although Edge packs all applicable styles inline:

```
 text/html 2053 <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer" style="background-color: rgb(40, 92, 118); border-bottom-color: currentColor; ...
```

It looks like there is some encoding problem between Chrome and Edge. Say Edge treats data as UTF-8 or UTF-16 while Chrome encodes as...

Any ideas how to fix/debug this? I do not see how to enforce particular encoding.

Chrome is 80.0.3987.87 and Edge 44.17763.831.0 in case this is some kind of bug right now.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue on Edge Legacy. But if you want the html code of the darg element, you could put below code in `dropHandler` as a workaround:

```
var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
console.log(event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))); //log the text/html part
```

Full example:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dropHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.traceDataTransfer(event.dataTransfer);
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  console.log(event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)));
}

function traceDataTransfer(data) {
  console.log(data.types);
  data.types.forEach((t) => {
    const value = data.getData(t);
    console.log(t, value.length, value);
  });
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">DataTransfer</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. But it will work only for drag and drop on the same page. What I do is - I drag a link from another browser window (any external site) where the source data is not in my control.

Comment: I see. It seems to be no good way to fix it in Edge. It might be a issue with the browser engine itself. I think you can make a compromise to only use the link url when drag from Chrome to Edge. Or try to use the latest Edge which is chromium based and have no issue like this.

Comment: yes, I'm using only link in this situation. in fact I have other situations where I get only the link. So either I create some approximate title out of a link or eventually I will have to bounce against the backend to get the page title anyway.